# Airflow depends_on_past explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

According to the [official Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html), 
The `task instances` directly upstream from the `task` need to be in a success state. Also, if you have set depends_on_past=True, the previous task instance needs to have succeeded (except if it is the first run for that task).

As all know, the task is kind of 'instantiated & parameteriazed' operator.

Now this is what confuse me. For example:

```
DAG: {op_1} -> {op_2} -> {op_3}
```

{op_2} is a simple PythonOperator that takes 1 parameter from {op_1} and do stuff;

To my understanding, op_2(param_1) & op_2(param_2) are considered as 2 different tasks.

Given `depends_on_past` is set to True, then:

1. If op_2(param_1) is still running; can op_2(param_2) be run?
2. If op_2(param_1) fails in the previous run; can op_2(param_1) be run in the current run?

Answer (score 37):

From the official [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) for trigger rules:

`depends_on_past` (boolean) when set to True, keeps a task from getting triggered if the previous schedule for the task hasn’t succeeded.

So unless a previous run of your DAG has failed, the `depends_on_past` should not be a factor, it will not affect the current run at all if the previous run executed the tasks successfully.

Comment: one point to note here is that the task remains in None state (not scheduled) when the task_instance for which depends_on_past is true and the task in previous schedule of the *scheduled dags* (schedule_interval is not None) is not successful. Depends on Past does not work on triggred DAGs

Comment: @Tameem "Depends on Past does not work on triggred DAGs" - is that true though?  I am manually triggering DAGs and tasks are in a none state with the task instance saying "depends_on_past is true for this task's DAG, but the previous task instance has not run yet.".  This is an externally triggered dag run.  Appreciate your thoughts since i dont see that mentioned in the docs - despite it making a lot of sense!

Comment: @Tameem "Depends on Past does not work on triggred DAGs"  - is there official documentation on this?

Comment: @theStud54 you did make a lot of sense... I rechecked the functionality on a simple DAG and it does work as expected. "@Abhilask Kishore" I had observed this when I was working on 1.9.0 but just to be sure before I post this comment, I executed the DAG with depends_on_past and my previous observation was incorrect.

Comment: This saved me.  I incorrectly thought `depends_on_past` only referred to the previous task success.